# Are memory leaks still possible with modern OS?

Tags: cpu, operating-systems, gpu, display-driver, memory-leaks

Are memory leaks still possible on Modern OS when the application exits? From my understanding, Modern OS manages memory quite well and will clear the memory once the application exits. This means that whenever there is a memory leak, I can just exit the offending application to fix the issue. Is this true?

Similarly, are memory leaks possible on the GPU? I am assuming that since the OS only manages CPU memory, GPUs are much more prone to memory leaks from crashes. Is there a similar mechanism on the drivers that monitors which application the memory belongs to on the GPU? Or is the only solution for GPU memory leaks a full restart?

Edit: Note: I am asking for when the application exits. I am aware the memory leaks are possible for any language during application runtime. **What im asking is what happens when the application exits, expectedly or unexpectedly due to an exception, for both CPU and GPU memory.**

Comment: Memory leaks are dependent on an application's access/usage of your RAM. They generally occur when a program is not optimized to re-use memory that has been allocated or will be re-allocated. To make it simple: some programs do not dump excess cache and as such the program eats more and more memory usage, causing memory leaks.

Comment: Although the general answer would be yes, I feel this question is primarily opinion based.

Comment: Note that a memory leak ceases to exist when a program exits. Memory leaks are internal to an application, and only occur when the program is running. once exited, all memory in use by the application is reclaimed, even if the application was managing that memory badly. Memory Leaks are a very specific phenomena experienced by applications that use a heap structure for storing data in abstract data types. it does not refer to more general losses of available memory, or even applications that use lots of memory or increase their consumption over time.

Comment: @FrankThomas Thanks for the answer. That was what im looking for. Can you extend the logic to GPU memory? does the same apply for GPU memory?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are still possible.  They occur when a programmer allocates memory and does not free that memory when they are done with it.

Comment: I know there are still possible within a program's runtime. I know its possible even with High level languages. The question is for when the application exits.